# Mackey's notation for "disjoint"

Tags: quantum-mechanics, notation, foundations

George W. Mackey uses this strange notation for "disjoint" in his book "Mathematical Foundations of Quantum Mechanics":

[image]

Or, in its context:

[image]

(see [here](https://books.google.hu/books?id=qlpb2mWYmfYC&pg=PA64&lpg=PA64&dq=%22we+shall+say+that%22+%22are+disjoint+and+write%22&source=bl&ots=eibtJbgim1&sig=ACfU3U1nQiXrMjquRbeAMPaZFlB27y9tvQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiW7uXVpLD6AhWcgP0HHWIpDIEQ6AF6BAgXEAM#v=onepage&q=%22we%20shall%20say%20that%22%20%22are%20disjoint%20and%20write%22&f=false))

What kind of symbol is this? Does it have a LaTeX version? Is it in use anywhere else?

Comment: I have never seem this notation before and I suspect there is no LaTeX version. I have checked up this table of LaTeX math symbols https://oeis.org/wiki/List_of_LaTeX_mathematical_symbols and didn't find it. But anyway, that's just me, maybe someone has seem this before and knows how to reproduce it in LaTeX.

Comment: If you're just looking for the latex symbol, it's probably worth asking on the [Latex.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).